# Why is this TypeScript class implementing the interface not assignable to a generic constraint extending the interface?

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I'm trying to develop some interfaces for linear algebra functions, because the world needs another linear algebra library. The (possibly bad) idea is to be able to specify `Vector` or `Matrix` for some higher level functions and have it just work, as long as the dimensions are correct.

I ran into some problems doing this with the `Vector` interface, but I discovered using `this` as a type and it resolved my issues (maybe I'm doing a bad thing here). I tried doing this in the `Matrix` interface, but because the arguments to the functions aren't of type `Matrix`, the `this` trick doesn't work.

I'm getting this same error for a lot of functions like this, but this is one example:

```
interface Vector {
  set (...args: number[]): this;
  setScalar (scalar: number): this;
  clamp (min: this, max: this): this;
  ...
}

class Vector2 implements Vector { ... }

interface Matrix {
  elements: number[];
  getRow<T extends Vector> (n: number): T;
  ...
}

class Matrix2 implements Matrix {
  private _elements: number[];
  public getRow (i: number): Vector2 {
    const te = this._elements;
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return new Vector2(te[0], te[2]);
      case 1:
        return new Vector2(te[1], te[3]);
      default:
        throw new Error('No row defined at ' + i + '.');
    }
  }
}
```

Constructing the interface this way, I get the following error message:

```
Property 'getRow' in type 'Matrix2' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Matrix'.
  Type '(i: number) => Vector2' is not assignable to type '<T extends Vector>(n: number) => T'.
    Type 'Vector2' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2416)
```

Vector2 implements the Vector interface, and the generic type constraint on `getRow()` requires the return type to be a type that implements the Vector interface.

Why I can't do things this way? I don't understand what this message is trying to tell me. I know I could probably work around this, but I also want to understand more about what's going on and maybe learn (!) something.

I'm using TypeScript 3.6.3.

Comment: `Matrix.setColumns()` says it must accept any number of arguments, of *any* subtype of `Vector` that the caller wants.  But `Matrix2.setColumns()` accepts exactly two arguments of only `Vector2`.  If I have a `Vector` object `v` and a `Matrix` object `m`, I should be allowed to call `m.setColumns(v)` on it.  But if `m` is a `Matrix2`, then that won't work... `v` might not be a `Vector2`, and I've only passed in one argument.  So `Matrix2` is not doing its job of implementing `Matrix`.

Comment: True, it's a bad implementation. But doesn't it technically fulfill the criteria specified? AFAICT, the function can take any number of arguments because Javascript, but we only use the first 2.

Comment: I changed the example to one that is less obviously bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the generic `T` can be specified at the call site, but `m.getRow` always returns a `Vector2`, no matter what the call site specifies for `T`.

For example, the following would be valid TypeScript, but doesn't work in your case. To prevent this situation from occurring, TypeScript will not compile and throw an error instead.

```
class Vector3 extends Vector { }

const m = new Matrix()
const row = m.getRow<Vector3>(0) // You specify a Vector3, but get a Vector2.
```

The easiest solution here would be to remove the generic and just declare `getRow` to always return a `Vector`:

```
interface Matrix {
  elements: number[];
  getRow(n: number): Vector;
}
```