# Unable to assign function to type with generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a problem which boils down to trying to assign a function with a specific parameter type to a variable expecting a function with a generic type:

```
const s: <T>(v: T)=>string 
  = (v: string[])=>(v[0]||'x');
```

[Playground version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=32#code/MYewdgzgLgBBBcMA8AVAfACgG6JQSgF41oAnASzAHMYAoGGAmbRUiygbQF1DMt2AGTgB8hAcgAeovAG4gA).

Typescript gives the following error:

> Type '(v: string[]) => string' is not assignable to type '(v: T) => string'. Types of parameters 'v' and 'v' are incompatible. Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

This error doesn't make much sense to me, as it seems like `string[]` is a perfectly reasonable type to use for the generic `T`.

There is a related question that has the same underlying problem, but the answer there was specific to circumstances in that question: [Why is this TypeScript class implementing the interface not assignable to a generic constraint extending the interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927538/why-is-this-typescript-class-implementing-the-interface-not-assignable-to-a-gene)

Comment: `<T>(v: T) => string` means the type of a function which can consume anything and output a string; your function can only consume an array of strings.

Comment: `const s: <T extends string[]>(v: T) => string
  = (v: string[]) => (v[0] || 'x');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by kaya3, you are trying to assign a function that take a specific type, `string[]`, to a function that takes generic types . What you may do instead, is, define a type with the generic signature. And then create a function that takes is one specific instance of that generic signature. Something like this:

```ts
type MyType<T> = (v: T) => string;
const s: MyType<string[]>  = (v: string[]) => v[0] || 'x' ;
```

If you have just one type, this would be sufficient:

```ts
const s  = (v: string[]) => v[0] || 'x' ;
```

Comment: That was my answer too, but I was six seconds late

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take a function that takes an array of strings and returns a string, and assign that function to a variable that takes any T and returns a string. A function that takes an array of strings as input cannot take any T as input.